Challenges with Login Processes, CAPTCHA Bypassing, and Bot Protection in Web Crawling
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I’m currently working on a web crawling project in Java where I need to handle different login processes for various websites. However, I’m facing several challenges, particularly with CAPTCHAs, login tokens, and bot protection mechanisms. I’m hoping to get some advice on the following issues:
1. Bypassing Bot Protections (e.g., CAPTCHAs, Blocks, Restrictions):
I'm currently using web unlocker services by BrightData to bypass these protections. However, this service isn't always effective, particularly on websites protected by BlazingFast DDos protection or Cloudflare. Is there a more reliable web unlocker service, or could a different technique help me overcome these issues?
2. Handling CAPTCHAs During Login:
I want to log in to web pages that include CAPTCHA challenges. I'm considering using CAPTCHA-solving services like DeathByCaptcha to bypass CAPTCHAs and then retrieve cookie information after a successful login. However, I haven't found any examples or guidance on how to do this. Can these CAPTCHA-solving services handle this process, and if so, could someone provide an example or explain how to implement it?
3. Logging in with Required Fields (e.g., Authentication Cookies):
To log in to certain web pages, I need to include specific fields, such as authentication cookies. I've been using Burp Proxy to examine network packets and identify the required fields for login. I'm also aware that JMeter could be used for this task. Which tool is better suited for this, or is there an even better approach I should consider?
4. Bypassing Bot Protections with Proxies and User-Agent Rotation:
My current strategy involves using web unlocker services, rotating proxies, and rotating user agents. I also introduce short timeouts before sending requests. Do you think these methods will help me effectively bypass bot protections and avoid getting blocked?
I'm facing a few challenges with this crawler project. While I've managed to partially solve some problems, others remain unresolved. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. If you're able to assist, please feel free to reach out privately, as I anticipate encountering new challenges as the project grows.
Thank you in advance for your help!
